# Ordering MySQL results to obey parent/child in Table of Contents

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data, tableofcontents

I have a table for a Table of Contents that looks like this:

- ID
- Parent_ID
- Chapter
- Display_Order

Each row is therefore a chapter heading, but there can be chapters within chapters, within chapters. Therefore the table above allows me to maintain these relationships.

If a Chapter has no parent, i.e. it is not the sub-chapter of any other chapter, Parent_ID is 'Null'. If a chapter does have a parent, it's Parent_ID is set to the parent chapter's ID.

Since there can be multiple sub chapters within a chapter, the order of these sub chapters is managed via the Display_Order column; 1 being first, etc.

Can anyone suggest a neat SQL query that would allow me to select the entire table, and produce a result that does the above? Essentially, I'm looking for a result set that reflects the actual hierarchy of the chapters. ASCII TOC below!

```
Chapter
-- Chapter
---- Chapter
---- Chapter
---- Chapter
-- Chapter
---- Chapter
---- Chapter
Chapter
Chapter
```

etc.

Comment: Is the ammount of levels known?

Comment: A single query would only be able to return all the results in Display_Order. You'd then just need to loop through the results and ident them depending on their Parent? If you can't get that working, possibly look into the adjacency list model: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/.

Comment: Even better would be the 'modified pre-order tree traversal' method mentioned on the next page of that article. This method allows him to get the full hierarchy in one simple query. http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: @Lumbendil the number of levels is not known, nor can it be fixed either as the Table of Contents needs to be very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it only with SQL queries (at least in MySQL). One of the approaches with SQL and PHP is the following:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(parent_id, 0) AS parentid, chapter FROM toc ORDER BY parentid, display_order
```

Then you read this rowset to an array $a like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $a[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['chapter'];
    $a[$row['parentid']]['children'][] = $row['id'];
}
```

It will create a fictive element with first index 0.

A small sample function to print the indent for a give level (you could use CSS with padding instead of   or any other means to generate the indent):

```
function printIndent($level = 0) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $level; $j++) echo '&nbsp';
}
```

Then you create a recursive function printTree that outputs the tree:

```
function printTree($key = 0, $level = 0) {
    if ($key > 0) {
         printIndent($level);
         echo $a[$key]['name'];
    }
    if (count($a[$key]['children'])
        foreach ($a[$key]['children'] as $child)
             printTree($child, $level + 1);
}
```

and you call it once with:

```
printTree();
```

This is it. Please note I skipped array initialisations and I did not run this sample code, so it might have syntax error but the principle it this one.

The drawback of this approach is that if you have a very large number of items it would not be the most effective as you read everything at once to a large array first. But for smaller number of items it is a good solution.

Comment: Forgot to add that it is very important to have exactly this ORDER BY of the SQL query as the way of generation of the array relies on this: the parents to be iterated before their children. And of course, it considers the display order of the children of one and same parent.

Comment: Many thanks. I agree, it's not massively scalable but it's a great step forward - this is really to prove a point at this stage and should we start playing with lots of data, I'd probably want to move to a database that supports recursion.